# Representing Objects as strings in VBA

Tags: strings, vba, interface

I am working an a more meaningful way to print objects in VBA.  The desired result should look something like this.

```
Console.PrintLine List.Create(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 2, 3)
```

The concept is that objects implementing an `IPrintable` interface are printed as their `ToString` property.  Primitive data types are printed as is

```
Console.PrintLine "a"
a
```

And other objects are represented as "TypeName(&ObjPtr)"

```
Console.PrintLine New Collection
Collection(&150653720)
```

But the issue that is gunking up my design is that I want nested objects to represent themselves

```
Console.PrintLine List.Create(1, List.Create(), New Collection)
List(1, List(), Collection(&150653384))
```

My solution is to use an auxiliary helper methods, located in a standard module called `cast`, which in a way provides a default implementation of `IPrintable`

```
Public Function ToString(ByVal x As Variant) As String

    Dim result As String

    If TypeOf x Is IPrintable Then
        result = x.ToString
    ElseIf IsObject(x) Then
        result = DefaultObjectToString(x)
    Else
        result = CStr(x)
    End If

    ToString = result

End Function
Private Function DefaultObjectToString(ByVal x As Object) As String

    DefaultObjectToString = ObjectToString(x, cast.CArray(Array("&" & ObjPtr(x))))

End Function
Public Function ObjectToString(ByVal o As Object, ByRef members() As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal delim As String = ", ") As String

    Dim stringMembers() As String
    If LBound(members) <= UBound(members) Then
        ReDim stringMembers(LBound(members) To UBound(members))
    End If

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(members) To UBound(members)
        stringMembers(i) = ToString(members(i))
    Next i

    ObjectToString = TypeName(o) & "(" & Join(stringMembers, delim) & ")"

End Function
```

I would want this to be located in the `IPrintable` class but that must be empty to use it as an interface.

Now any method that is printing the objects can just use `cast.ToString` like console does

```
Public Sub PrintLine(Optional ByVal x As Variant)

    If IsMissing(x) Then
        Debug.Print vbNullString
    Else
        Debug.Print cast.ToString(x)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Also here is how `List` implements `IPrintable` (`ToArray` is just an array version of the list.)

```
Public Property Get ToString(Optional delim As String = ", ") As String

    ToString = cast.ObjectToString(Me, ToArray, delim)

End Property
Public Property Get IPrintable_ToString() As String

    IPrintable_ToString = ToString()

End Property
```

If I had a BinaryTree object it would look like this.

```
Public Property Get ToString() As String

    ToString = cast.ObjectToString(Me, Array(LeftTree, RightTree), ", ")

End Property
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to look at this. Can you elaborate on why you want `Cast` to be a class?

Comment: `cast` is a standard module not a class. I will update the post to specify

Comment: Right. I get that, but I don't understand why exactly you need it to be a class. It seems an appropriate use for a module.

Comment: @RubberDuck because "static" VBA classes are so much cooler! :)

Comment: @RubberDuck There really isn't an appropriate place for it.  It really should be in IPrintable as a default implementation, but those don't exist in VBA.  Making it a static class implies that I should be able to pass it as an argument but idk if that should be allowed or not.

Comment: I'd love to see this `Cast` module!

Comment: Yeah. I think so too.. seems like that's where a bit part of your concern lies. I am understanding your struggle now though. You need a base class, but inheritance doesn't work that way in VBA.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Currently they are separated so the above code was in [cast](https://github.com/ptwales/VBEX/blob/master/src/cast.bas), but is now in [Printable](https://github.com/ptwales/VBEX/blob/master/src/Printable.cls)

Comment: I would create an `IComparer` and *imitate* overriding .Net's  `.ToString()` - sort of like it was done [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19908375/2140173)... or imitate a static class like `Convert` with only supported data types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything ugly about your `Cast` module. If it was .Net I would use a `Static` (`Shared`) type class, and a standard *.bas module is roughly equivalent in VB6. It seems to have been the right move to me.

What I do question is the usefulness of defaulting to the object's pointer as a string representation of it. Since VB6 supports default properties, I would take advantage of it. It's not exactly pretty, but perhaps a more useful representation of an object.

```
Private Function TryCastToString(x As Variant) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    TryCastToString = CStr(x)

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Const MethodNotSupportedError As Integer = 438

    If Err.Number = MethodNotSupportedError Then
        TryCastToString = "&" & ObjPtr(x)
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Function
```

Which would change this function:

> ```
> Private Function DefaultObjectToString(ByVal x As Object) As String
>
>     DefaultObjectToString = ObjectToString(x, cast.CArray(Array("&" & ObjPtr(x))))
>
> End Function
> ```

Into this:

```
Private Function DefaultObjectToString(ByVal x As Object) As String

    DefaultObjectToString = ObjectToString(x, cast.CArray(Array(TryCastToString(x))))

End Function
```

---

This provides a much nicer string back. Consider a workbook with a value of "Hello!" in cell A1 and the following code.

```
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print Cast.ToString(ThisWorkbook)
    Debug.Print Cast.ToString(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

This would result in the following:

> ```
> Workbook(&2349672)
> Range(Hello!)
> ```